# What is the best live chat extension for magento 2?

Tags: magento2, integration

I'm looking for the live chat extension for magento 2. After my reserach I noticed that most of them have their own panel and not integrated with magento 2 in the way I would like. So if agent has to do something with order/cart

is  there an extension which offer features like:

- agent has access to quote/order of customer and can add/remove items
- agent can see which product is being viewed by the customer

I generally need the extension which has the best integration with magento 2

Comment: Live chat free extension.
https://marketplace.magento.com/livechat-module-magento-livechat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of live chat extension list for Magento 2 here

https://www.mageplaza.com/review/live-chat/

But I personally suggest using http://www.unbeatable.com/ this free extension for the chat, I have used it's on many websites.

This is free